# How come my fork/exec and close is losing the error code from the child

Tags: perl, fork, exec

I have a piece of perl code that is roughly like this

```
my $pid = open(PIPE, '-|');
die "Unable to fork: $!\n" if !defined $pid;
if ($pid == 0)
{
    open STDERR, '>&STDOUT' or die "Can't redirect STDERR to STDOUT\n";
    exec(@cmd);
    die "Unexpected exec failure: $!\n";
}
my @lines = (<PIPE>);
close PIPE;
if ($? != 0) { do stuff; }
```

However, for reasons I can't understand, possibly related to the actual program being called not existing, sometimes this fails to pick up the error from the child in `$?`

`@lines` contains the "Unexpected exec failure: File or directory does not exist" as expected (and some other output from a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler), but `$?` is set to 0. I'm working round this for now by also checking the return from `close` which is fortunately set to 1. But where did my error code go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found what it was.

Someone had added an `END{}` block in a library that was destroying the return codes (by calling system and hence destroying $?). I backed out the change and everything was happy.

Comment: I would still switch to `open3` for its better error handling

Comment: You could have added `local $?;` before the call to `system`

Comment: So the question was not answerable with the code actually presented; maybe you should update the question to make it reproducible. Also "man perlmod" explains: "*Inside an "END" code block, $? contains the value that the program is going to pass to "exit()".*", so basically the `END` block needs fixing!

Comment: well, i wasn't aware that someone had added an end block in a library used by the thing that was being called since the original code was written. That's a very nasty action at a distance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know. It shouldn't happen. You could use the following instead:

```
use IPC::Open qw( open3 );

my $pid = open3(local *PIPE, '>&STDOUT', undef, @cmd);
while (<PIPE>) {
   ...
}

waitpid($pid, 0);
```

Bonus: An error that occur while launching the child (e.g. an error from duping or from `exec`) throws an exception in the *parent*, so it doesn't look like the command ran and returned an error.